# Distribution for the lowest value in a list of values selected uniformly at random

Tags: probability, distributions, uniform-distribution, discrete-data

If I select `N` values at random from the discrete uniform distribution on the integers `[1, 2, ..., M]` what is the probability distribution for the *smallest* value?

I'm interested in the discrete probability distribution, but also in a continuous approximation for it (so I could sample randomly from it).

I guess in a sense it's something like the inverse of the [german tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)?

Comment: The answer appears as part of the solution to the more complicated question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253990.  It is also stated in the question itself.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Dealing_with_discrete_variables

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(i)$ the probability function of the distribution of the smallest value.

$$P(i)=P(\text{the smallest value = i})=$$
$$=P(\text{no value < i }\,\cap\,\text{at least one value = i} )=$$
$$=P(\text{all values} \ge i)·P(\text{at least one value = i | all values} \ge i)$$

You haven't mentioned it, but if we can assume that the $N$ values are chosen independently and with replacement, $P(\text{all values} \ge i)$ and $P(\text{at least one value = i | all values} \ge i)$ can be computed using just the binomial distribution.

$M-i+1$ of the $M$ possible values are larger or equal than $i$, then:

$$P(\text{all values} \ge i)=\bigg(\frac{M-i+1}{M}\bigg)^N$$

And among the $M-i+1$ values larger or equal than $i$, $M-i$ are larger than $i$, then:

$$P(\text{at least one value = i | all values} \ge i)=$$
$$=1-P(\text{all values > i | all values} \ge i)=$$
$$=1-\bigg(\frac{M-i}{M-i+1}\bigg)^N$$

Then:

$$P(i)=P(\text{the smallest value = i})=$$
$$=\bigg(\frac{M-i+1}{M}\bigg)^N·\bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{M-i}{M-i+1}\bigg)^N\bigg)$$

And just an example:

```
> N<-6
> M<-10
> i<-1:M
> pti<-((M-i+1)/M)^N
> pai<-1-((M-i)/(M-i+1))^N
> (pr<-pti*pai)
 [1] 0.468559 0.269297 0.144495 0.070993 0.031031 0.011529 0.003367 0.000665 0.000063 0.000001
```

That is, if you randomly chose 6 numbers with replacement from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, the probability of the smallest being 1 is 48.86%, of being 2 is 26.92%, and so.

Comment: It needs to be noted that this is a solution for selection *with replacement*: values that are selected may include duplicates.  It would be of interest to have a solution to the more difficult part of the question: what is an efficient way to generate data from this distribution?

Comment: "with replacement" added. Without replacement, the solution would be similar but using factorials instead of exponentiation. @whuber Thanks for pointing.

Comment: For this "with replacement" case, a fast way to generate from it is as follows: If $U$ is uniform  then $M-\lfloor M U^{1/N}\rfloor$ should have the required distribution. In R on my laptop generating a million values this way (`x = m-trunc(m*runif(nsim)^(1/n))` with `m=6` and `n=3`) seems to take less than a second. (This essentially generates the maximum via the inverse-cdf method and flips it end-for-end to get the distribution of the minimum. I expect @whuber had already thought of this approach or something quite similar to it. )